# Pegar informações digitadas em um iframe

Tags: javascript, html5, iframe

Tenho uma página HTML que tem um elemento `iframe`.

Esse iframe possui um cadastro. Eu preciso salvar as informações que são digitadas dentro do iframe (outro domínio).

Em minhas pesquisas, verifiquei a possibilidade de utilizar [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), porém não encontrei uma forma de usar conforme minha necessidade.

Comment: Esse outro iFrame tem CORS aberto?

Comment: Esse iframe seria o site da Receita. O que eu preciso fazer é salvar as informações do cadastro de cupons fiscais de uma ONG. Ela recebe os cupons (doação) e os "digitadores" colocam as informações. Eu gostaria de salva-las em um banco de dados para criar relatórios. Será que é possível?

Comment: creio que isso não seja possível...